# Android EditText exceeded it's parent viewgroup

Tags: android, android-layout

[image: snapshot]

As shown in the above screenshot, the EditText exceeded it's parent, how to prevent this from happening?

In my chat activity I use a ListView to display messages, each message is a list item

This is the xml file:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/form"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:padding="5dp" >
</ListView>
```

And list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatarLeft"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty_string"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_default_avatar"
        android:visibility="gone" />           this will be adjusted programmatically

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"        this will be adjusted programmatically
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/none"    this will be adjusted programmatically
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatarRight"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:contentDescription="@string/empty_string"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_default_avatar"
        android:visibility="gone" />           this will be adjusted programmatically

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given wrap_content for textview width whihc is causing this issue. Best would be to use a Relative layout there rather than Linear Layout.

But in case you want to use LinearLayout only use match parent and rather than giving padding, use margin_left like below:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"     this will be adjusted programmatically
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/none" this will be adjusted programmatically
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't mind changing to relativelayout, but I cannot make it match_parent because the message could be shorter than that, any ideas?

Comment: In that case keep wrap_content and use marginLeft rather than paddingLeft. marginLeft works with respect to the boundaries and paddingLeft will work with respect to the view components.

Comment: Sorry for the misleading information, I don't really need that margin/padding property so I removed it, and issue still exists...

Comment: Add your TextView inside LinearLayout and set its width to match_parent. I have edited my code. Please have a look at it